# adapter.setHasStableIds(true) why it is not enabled by default in RecyclerView?

Tags: android, performance, android-recyclerview

I can see setting adapter.

> setHasStableIds(true);

will improved RecyclerView performance, since it is improving lots of performance, why it is not default enabled in `RecyclerView`, Is there any limitations while setting `setHasStableIds(true)`?

Answer (score 2):

The reason why it is not the default is because the data backing the adapter might not have stable Id's and the RecyclerView does not know this.

Yes there is a limitation one using `setHasStableIds(true)` - your data has to have stable Id's

You either need override getItemId(int position) to return a unique Id that would represent each Data Item, simply return the HashCode if you cannot think of anything better.

Or

If using something like a `CursorAdapter` this automatic has stable Id's as it uses the database table _id column.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is when we are going to  just displaying the data in recycler-view that case  no need to unique id of each item and no  animation required. so it's  **default its false**.

But when we are going to perform some action in the dataset and update the recycler-view that case its need unique id for particular item and refreshing animation (blinking) it need.so we set as  **true**